# Why is it that sometimes `f.write` will write at the end of my file, and sometimes it will overwrite at the beginning?

Tags: python, file, file-writing

So I've been messing around with `write`.

In my folder, I have a text file called `test.txt` which contains `abcdefg`.

If I run the following script:

```
with open('test.txt', mode='r+') as f:
    f.write('test')
```

the `test.txt` file now contains `testefg`

And for some reason, if I instead run the following script: (starting back with `abcdefg` in `test.txt`)

```
with open('test.txt', mode='r+') as f:
    f.read()
    f.write('test')
```

Now the `test.txt` file contains `abcdefgtest`

Also, I don't really understand what `mode='r+'` does because I can't find it in any documentation. Some sources on the internet said that it was for both reading and writing in the file. I suspect it behaves the same as `'+'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function)

Comment: A file has an *internal file pointer*, and depending on where it is, that's where you write. `read` moves the file pointer to the end…

Comment: Alright, that's clear.

Comment: @Wouter my question was more precisely about why adding `f.read()` in a line makes a difference, and not entirely about what the modes did, but thank you for the link that was useful